# Getting file name out of a string

Tags: php

I need to get the filename '**HomeModel**' out of a string **app\model\common\HomeModel**. This is what I tried

First, replace '\' with '/' using the str_replace.

```
$model = 'app\model\common\HomeModel';
$file = str_replace("\\", '/', $model) . ".php";
echo $file;
```

the result

```
app/model/common/HomeModel.php
```

then I explode the result like so

```
$model = 'app\model\common\HomeModel';
$file = str_replace("\\", '/', $model) . ".php";
echo $file;

$result = explode("/", $file);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($result);
```

and then this is what I have

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'app' (length=3)
  1 => string 'model' (length=5)
  2 => string 'common' (length=6)
  3 => string 'HomeModel.php' (length=18)
```

Now, how do I get the last value 'HomeModel' out of this array for further use?, I need to assign the value 'HomeModel' to $class.

Comment: If you want to assign the last entry in an array to a variable, `$class = end($result);` should do the job.

Comment: @MCMXCII, thank you buddy ... solved.

Comment: No problem. Feel free, when you get a sec, to accept the below answer so this question gets closed off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`end()` should do the job.

```
$class = end($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pathinfo function

```
$file = str_replace("\\", '/', $model) . ".php";
echo pathinfo($file)['filename']; // HomeModel
```

Answer (score 2):

While `end()` is the answer to this specific question, I would encourage other members to try a better approach regarding the case of breaking a path to its parts using the php function [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
echo $path_parts['basename']; // since PHP 5.2.0. Output: lib.inc.php
```

In your example, just use the first str_replace so it would be a valid path and manually add the php extension to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$class = $result[count($result)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
<?php

$model = 'app\model\common\HomeModel';

$fileName = substr(str_replace("\\", '/',$model), strrpos(str_replace("\\", '/',$model),'/') + 1).'.php';

echo $fileName;
```